# kendo ui datepicker submit to asp.net controller is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Test"))
{
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input kendo-date-picker
           k-format="'dd/MM/yyyy'"
           k-ng-model="Birthday"
           placeholder="Birthday"
           id="Birthday"
           name="Birthday"               
           class="form-control"
           style="width: 100%;" type="date" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
}
<script>

angular.module("myApp", ["kendo.directives"]).controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

});
</script>
```

and asp.net mvc controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(DateTime? Birthday = null)
{
    DateTime? temp = Birthday;
    return View();
}
```

If i set server datetime by en-US is Birthday always null, but set by vi-VN then OK. How can i take Birthday value and don't change server datetime and keep format for datepicker ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options:

- [match the server and client culture](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization#match-cultures)
- change the DatePicker's `format` to be compatible with the server-side culture - in this way the server-side binder will be able to parse the submitted value as `DateTime` automatically
- handle the `Birthday` value as a `String` in the action method and transform it to a `DateTime` manually